# Dynamically loading SpringBean by environment var

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I'm trying to figure out the best way to load a spring bean, depending on a system environment variable being set. I realize that this would be a simple task using profiles, but unfortunately I'm using Spring 2.5. So here is the bean definition in my XML file:

```
<bean id="updateBlogEntryListenerContainer"
          class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationName" value="queue/updateBlogEntryQueue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="updateBlogEntryMessageHandler"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="destinationResolver"/>
</bean>
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to only load that bean based on the existence of a system environment variable, otherwise, ignore it. I've been looking into the use of BeanPostProcessors and BeanFactoryPostProcessors, but can't quite put my finger on the solution. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a FactoryBean that would check the environment variable and create the actual bean or some NoOp implementation - returning a null from the FactoryBean might also work if it is not referenced anywhere.

```
class ListenerContainerFactory extends FactoryBean<MessageListenerContainer> {

     MessageListenerContainer getObject() {
        if (someCondition) {
            // create and return DefaultMessageListenerContainer
        } else {
            // return null or some NoOpMessageListenerContainer
        }
     }
}
```